# trigger_file doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, replication

I set streaming replication. Replication works just fine but it doesn't care about trigger_file. I have nothing fancy there except all what many of tutorials advices:

**recovery.conf:**

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=69.69.69.69 port=5432 user=repl password=some_pass_here'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/failover_trigger'
```

I've checked that the `postgres` user has access to this file, I've tried to change the location to `/tmp`, set file owner as `postgres` or `root` and nothing helped.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't mention it explicitly: Are you trying to failover?

Comment: yes, definitely :)

Comment: Do the logs tell you something happening when you create the file?

Comment: Nothing at all - I have `tail -f` on it and trying to play with the file. Whatever I do nothing happens.

Comment: I run `pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main promote` and it worked but `recovery.conf` didn't changed its name to `recovery.done`.

Comment: That would indicate the `recovery.conf` you're looking at is ignored by postgres. At least that's consistent with its `trigger_file` being ignored too.

Comment: How it can be if it uses values from this file to connect to the master ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a starting point to troubleshoot this, you may check what's read from `recovery.conf` with `log_min_messages` set to `debug2` in `postgresql.conf` on the slave.

On server start, the trigger file should be shown in the log within a set of entries like this:

```
 DEBUG:  standby_mode = 'on'
 DEBUG:  primary_conninfo = 'host=69.69.69.69 port=5432 user=repl password=some_pass_here'
 DEBUG:  trigger_file = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/failover_trigger'
 LOG:  entering standby mode
```

If the `trigger_file` entry doesn't show up, the most plausible explanation would be that you're editing a `recovery.conf` at a wrong location.

If on the other hand it's found at startup, when later creating the trigger file to fail over, this entry should appear:

```
 LOG:  trigger file found: /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/failover_trigger
```

Comment: Got it ! I did as you advised and I noticed 2 things: `1st:` there was no trigger_file in the log and `2nd:` it doesn't care if I change something in `primary_conninfo` - so I've started looking for another file and I found it in `/var/lib/postgresql..` (mine was in `/etc/postgres/..`). Finally I found the reason: `pg_basebackup -R` which uses `.pgpass` to connect and than `-R` saves the credentials to new `recovery.conf`. It tricked me so much :) Thank you for help.

Answer (score -1):

once the trigger is created on the master machine

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=69.69.69.69 port=5432 user=repl password=some_pass_here'
trigger_file = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/failover_trigger'
```

you need to create the file in the slave machine (replica) in-order to reconfigure itself to lunch your trigger

**EDIT**

lets check the configuration after the installation is completed:

1) you need a ssh key,if you don't have one you can generate one for testing, but it will give you certificate error later by using `ssh-keygen`

2)copy the certificate you had in step one to the other server: `ssh-copy-id IP_address_of_opposite_server`

3) create replica user by using `psql -c "CREATE USER rep REPLICATION LOGIN CONNECTION LIMIT 1 ENCRYPTED PASSWORD ' enter_your_password';`

****Note the following steps need to be done while the service is down if you want to do it at the sometime otherwise you can repeat the steps for replica machine (slave).**

4)open PostgreSQL directory

5)edit (pg_hba.conf) file note: take a backup from (`pg_hba.conf`) first

6)  add the following line but make sure you font add it to the bottom of the file: `host    replication  rep  IP_address_of_slave/32   md5`

7) save and close

8) edit (`postgresql.conf`) note  you need to take backup first

9) search for the following parameters and um-comment them

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,IP_address_of_THIS_host'
wal_level = 'hot_standby'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'
max_wal_senders = 1
hot_standby = on
```

10) save and close

11) start the master machine (main server that has the database make sure the replica service still down)

12) now you need to take backup from the master machine by using

```
psql -p $PORT -c "select pg_start_backup('$BACKUP_LABEL');"
rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* $PGDATA/ <IP_OF_OTHER_HOST>:$PGDATA/
psql -p $PORT -c "select pg_stop_backup();"
```

13) now open `recovery.conf` on the replica server

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=master_IP_address port=[unter port number] user=rep password=[enter rep password]'
trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.port'
```

14) start the replica server

15) make sure the ports are opened in the firewall.

16) to open the turn over you need to touch the trigger file that mentioned in the `recovery.conf`

Comment: I have nothing like this on the master. `recovery.conf` is on the slave and the trigger file I'm creating there as well (with `touch /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/failover_trigger`). I don't get what do you mean writing 'once the trigger is created on the master machine'.

Comment: Please check the edited part on my answer above. hope that will help you

Comment: What you've wrote here is one more step-by-step tutorial how to set streaming replication - very similar to the one I followed. As I wrote in the Q replication works just fine and I can rollover with `pg_ctl`/`pg_ctlcluster`. What I would like to focus at is the reason why it doesn't care about the trigger file. I can provide any additional info that is necessary - just tell me what you need.

Comment: Please use the the PostgreSQL user and its users